# Header extension issue HTML & CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a header file which has the navigation menu in it which I include on every page using function (`<?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>` ). But weirdly some things like my "search" button on pages other then home (index) look differently (I mean header.css dosent work with some elements)!
I will attach screenshots of the home and signup page below so you can see what I mean.
Another "header" releated issue happens when I add  tag on the index page (to create side menu) it looks like the css of the "header" although "header" has its own css and index has another one.
Can someone tell me why this is happening! Apparently I cant add images here yet but if you click on teh files below it will open up and you will see what I mean. Thanks

Index page

```
<?php
  include_once 'header.php';
?>

<head>
  <title>{{ title }}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="category-tree">
    <h4 class="cat-title">Categories</h4>
    <nav>
      <ul class="left-menu-categories">
        <li class="cat-1"><a href="#" title="Estate">Title</a></li>
        <li class="cat-1"><a href="#" title="Estate">Title</a></li>
        <li class="cat-1"><a href="#" title="Estate">Title</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Header file

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PHP Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/header.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav>
      <img src="static/img/logo.png" href="index.php" style="width: 100px">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul>
          <div class="search-bar">
            <form>
              <input class="search-box" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search...">
              <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {
              echo "<li><button class='sell' href=''>Button</button></li>";
              echo "<li><a href='profile.php'>My Profile</a></li>";
              echo "<li><a href='includes/logout.inc.php'>Log out</a></li>";
            }
            else {
              echo "<li><a href='signup.php'>Sign Up</a></li>";
              echo "<li><a href='login.php'>Login</a></li>";
            }
          ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </body>

<div class="wrapper">
```

Home page
[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq87i.png)

Login page
[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjcEX.png)

Comment: Your include file is an entire HTML page - so when it is included you will have a page with two head,2bodies etc etc - a mongrel as it were.

Comment: The include file should just include the necessary markup for where it is to be included ( unless it is used as an iframe source. Also, you should include it at the point where it is needed

Comment: remove `</body>` place it in footer.php

Comment: But how am I supposed to make it "non entire HTML " page in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a serversided language. Include parses a file server sided into another file befor it is sended to users browser for rendering.

So your document would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PHP Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/header.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav>
      <img src="static/img/logo.png" href="index.php" style="width: 100px">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul>
          <div class="search-bar">
            <form>
              <input class="search-box" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search...">
              <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {
              echo "<li><button class='sell' href=''>Button</button></li>";
              echo "<li><a href='profile.php'>My Profile</a></li>";
              echo "<li><a href='includes/logout.inc.php'>Log out</a></li>";
            }
            else {
              echo "<li><a href='signup.php'>Sign Up</a></li>";
              echo "<li><a href='login.php'>Login</a></li>";
            }
          ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </body>

<div class="wrapper">

<head>
  <title>{{ title }}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="category-tree">
    <h4 class="cat-title">Categories</h4>
    <nav>
      <ul class="left-menu-categories">
        <li class="cat-1"><a href="#" title="Estate">Title</a></li>
        <li class="cat-1"><a href="#" title="Estate">Title</a></li>
        <li class="cat-1"><a href="#" title="Estate">Title</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

to which you surely agree would be an invalid HTML markup. You have multipel `<head>` and `<body>` sections.

Your actual files should look like this:

**Index.php:**

```
<?php
  include_once 'header.php';
?>

  <div class="category-tree">
    <h4 class="cat-title">Categories</h4>
    <nav>
      <ul class="left-menu-categories">
        <li class="cat-1"><a href="#" title="Estate">Title</a></li>
        <li class="cat-1"><a href="#" title="Estate">Title</a></li>
        <li class="cat-1"><a href="#" title="Estate">Title</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**header.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PHP Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/header.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav>
      <img src="static/img/logo.png" href="index.php" style="width: 100px">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul>
          <div class="search-bar">
            <form>
              <input class="search-box" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search...">
              <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {
              echo "<li><button class='sell' href=''>Button</button></li>";
              echo "<li><a href='profile.php'>My Profile</a></li>";
              echo "<li><a href='includes/logout.inc.php'>Log out</a></li>";
            }
            else {
              echo "<li><a href='signup.php'>Sign Up</a></li>";
              echo "<li><a href='login.php'>Login</a></li>";
            }
          ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Ok so I have tried doing it as you did. But nothing really changed. The problem still remains the same. My header.css file is being recognised on the index page when it actually should effect only the "header" as index page has its own css

Comment: then then an issue with your CSS and selectors. Like I said. The 2 files are emrged as one HTMl file server sided. So the user only has 1 HTML file not 2. And certainly you cant use a CSS file to only efefct one part of the files (as theere is only one file in the browser).